# How to mock the Google Workflow call from Google-cloud-client-libraries in a unit test

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-workflows

I am using Google Workflow from Google Cloud. I need to trigger the execution of a given Google Workflow from my java microservice.

My app is a Spring-boot application but I don't know if it matters.

The way I trigger the workflow is the following, based on the google documentation: https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/execute-workflow-client-libraries

```
        try (ExecutionsClient executionsClient = ExecutionsClient.create()) {
            WorkflowName workflow = WorkflowName.of(workflowProperties.getProjectId(), workflowProperties.getLocation(), workflowProperties.getName());
            
            Execution arguments = Execution.newBuilder().setArgument(String.format("{ \"executionId\": \"%s\" }", executionId)).build();
            CreateExecutionRequest request =
                    CreateExecutionRequest.newBuilder()
                            .setParent(workflow.toString())
                            .setExecution(arguments)
                            .build();
            Execution response = executionsClient.createExecution(request);
            if (!response.hasError()) {
                ... LOG everything is fine
            } else {
                ... LOG the error
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            ... LOG / handle exception
        }
```

In my unit/mockito test I get a 404 error because the test cannot reach google. I need to mock the actual call to Google, and to do this I probably need to mock `ExecutionsClient.create()`.

This is a static call and I don't want to use powerMockito in my test to mock static stuff. Is there any other option?

Comment: One approach is to wrap that static call in your own Factory, and inject the Factory through the constructor.  Then for the unit test, mock the Factory to have it return whatever is needed as usual.

Comment: Understood. But it still does not work.. My factory return `ExecutionsClient.create()` for prod code, and I mocked the method in my mockito test so it returns `mock(ExecutionsClient.class)`. But when the line `executionsClient.createExecution(request);` is reached I get an exceptio:   `ExecutionsClient.stub.something()` throws an exception because `stub` is null. It's like the `ExecutionsClient` is not fully mocked deep inside the object

Comment: Not sure what you mean - if the Factory is mocked, then `ExecutionsClient.create()` should not be invoked in the test.

Comment: ExecutionsClient.create() is not invoked but this:  `mock(ExecutionsClient.class).createExecution(request)` does not work, and I don't understand why